# Rename images while uploading and put in specific folder

Tags: entities, files

I am using drupal 7.

I have created an Advertisement content type. This contains a field where end user can upload images of their Brands.

I want to rename the images which are uploaded by the field of content type and put in specific folder named user id of the user. So uploaded file location would look like it:
/sites/default/files/images/user_id/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[File (Field) Paths](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) let you set file name and file path for file field:

[image]